# Linq GroupBy anonymous type error MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have the code below that  uses group to selects distinct values.  Intellisence  and   code break shows the query is working as expected.

```
public ActionResult _PortfoliosbyCountry()
    {
        var portfolios = db.Portfolios;
        var query = (from t in portfolios
                     group t by new { t.UserId, t.CountryId,t.PortfolioTypeId }
                         into grp
                         select new 
                         {
                             grp.Key.CountryId,
                             grp.Key.PortfolioTypeId,
                             grp.Key.UserId  
                         }).ToList();


        return PartialView(query);
    }
```

Model

```
namespace RefST.Models
{
public class Portfolio
{
    [Key]
    public int PId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml][Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int UserId {get; set; }     
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int PortfolioTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual PortfolioType PortfolioType { get; set; }
}
}
```

The problem is the razor view which gives the following error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type: **'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType19`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RefST.Models.Portfolio]'**.

```
@model IEnumerable<RefST.Models.Portfolio>

<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table>
 <tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CountryId)
    </th>


    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PortfolioTypeId)
    </th>

    <th></th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var b in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.UserId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.CountryId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.PortfolioTypeId)
    </td>
  </tr>
 }
 </table>
```

I will be grateful if anyone could point me to the right direction

Comment: Could you show the code of your `PortFolio` model?

Comment: The error is saying that you are grouping into anonymous type, just add Portfolio after select new. So select new Portfolio{grp.key. etc}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this line you could do like this:

```
select new PortFolio
                     {
                        countryId= grp.Key.CountryId,
                        PortfolioTypeId= grp.Key.PortfolioTypeId,
                        UserId= grp.Key.UserId,
                        //Add others members with default value
                        Titel=string.Empty;
                        ....  
                     }).ToList();
```

So you are sure that You send a `IEnumerable<Portfolio>` as a `Model`

Comment: I tried you reccommendation but get further error The entity or complex type 'RefST.Models.Portfolio' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: do you suggest I create a viewmodel for my required fields?

Comment: YOu can also. As you use just 3 properties in Portfolio. But in the meantime you could change somewhere else the code. Think wisely about it.

Comment: I created a PortfolioFilterViewModel for those 3 properties and it worked fine if I just replace  select new Portfolio with select new PortfolioFilterViewModel

Answer (score 4):

If you strip away the excessive .NET generic syntax, the error message is pretty clear about what's going wrong:

> `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type: 'List<AnonymousType<int, int, int>>', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'IEnumerable<Portfolio>'.`

In your code, if you ignore the grouping, you are essentially doing this:

```
from x in y ... 
select new { CountryId = x.a, PortfolioTypeId = x.b, UserId = x.c }
```

which produces an anonymous type that happens to have three integer fields. Although you haven't given that type a name, the *compiler* has given it a name, something that you couldn't never use in C# for your own types (in this case, it's called `<>f__AnonymousType19`).

When two anonymous types have the same fields of the same type in the same order, the compiler treats them as the same type. However, an anonymous type is *never* the same type as anything you have named yourself, and the compiler isn't going to automatically convert between them. Your Razor view expects a list of objects of type `Portfolio`, and you sent it a list of objects that were not that. The fact that your anonymous type happens to have the correct three fields isn't relevant to the compiler -- it's just plain the *wrong type*.

Fortunately, it's an easy fix. Select the correct named type in the LINQ query:

```
from x in y ... 
select new Portfolio { CountryId = x.a, PortfolioTypeId = x.b, UserId = x.c }
```

Comment: That is really informative but I will give the tick to inanikan cos he was the first to assist

Comment: @Diin - you can up-vote both of them to show they are good and useful answers (as I did).